# How to save sorted list of files in the current directory

Tags: linux

How do I...

1. Display sorted filename in the current path.
2. Redirect sorted filename in the current path to “sortedlist.txt

Comment: You might get downvoted, but I appreciate your to the point, succinct question :D

Answer (score 1):

1. `ls | sort`, read [the manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) for different sorting orders and whatnot
2. `ls | sort > sorttedlist.txt` (this is just output redirection to a file)

Comment: `ls` output by default is sorted alphabetically, no need for `sort`. `ls -1` will give you the list output

Comment: That's correct, updating the answer. TY!